# "ValueError: arrays must all be same length"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

In a machine learning project, suppose I have 3 cat images and 2 dog images. when I make a dataframe for the training data.

```
#pre processing train data
filenames = os.listdir('/content/train') 
categories = []

for filename in os.listdir('/content/train'):
  category = filename.split('.')[0]
  if category == 'dog' :
    categories.append(1) #1 for dog and 0 for cat
  else :
    categories.append(0)

#make a dictonary
df = pd.DataFrame(        
    {
     'filename' : filenames,
     'category':categories
    }
)
```

It gives an error because I haven't the same amount of dog, cat images.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-2d4e2440ba41> in <module>()
     12       {
     13           'filename' : filenames,
---> 14           'category' : categories
     15       }
     16   )

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in extract_index(data)
    395             lengths = list(set(raw_lengths))
    396             if len(lengths) > 1:
--> 397                 raise ValueError("arrays must all be same length")
    398 
    399             if have_dicts:

ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

Is there any way to fix it without adding any image to the training dataset?

Comment: Hi. It has nothing to do with unequal number of cat/dogs images. It seems problem lies somewhere else. when you put `filenames` and `category` columns into the DataFrame `pandas` says they are not of equal length which is weird but is not related to the proportion of dogs/cats. Please restart your notebook and try again. It seems like `os.listdir('/content/train')` changed state between calls or something... Also please put your error in the formatted text instead of image :))